# Copy vector of values to vector of pairs in one line

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, stl

I have the following types:

```
struct X { int x; X( int val ) : x(val) {} };
struct X2 { int x2; X2() : x2() {} };

typedef std::pair<X, X2>      pair_t;
typedef std::vector<pair_t>   pairs_vec_t;
typedef std::vector<X>        X_vec_t;
```

I need to initialize instance of `pairs_vec_t` with values from `X_vec_t`. I use the following code and it works as expected:

```
int main()
{
  pairs_vec_t ps;
  X_vec_t xs; // this is not empty in the production code

  ps.reserve( xs.size() );

  { // I want to change this block to one line code.
    struct get_pair {
      pair_t operator()( const X& value ) { 
        return std::make_pair( value, X2() ); }
    };
    std::transform( xs.begin(), xs.end(), back_inserter(ps), get_pair() );
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to reduce my copying block to one line with using `boost::bind`. This code is not working:

```
for_each( xs.begin(), xs.end(), boost::bind( &pairs_vec_t::push_back, ps, boost::bind( &std::make_pair, _1, X2() ) ) );
```

<strike>I know why it is not working</strike>, but I want to know how to make it working without declaring extra functions and structs?

Comment: Nooo!  This isn't Perl!  I prefer the readable version :)

Comment: I will not use `bind` in the production code if final result will look unreadable. Honestly :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

something like this?

```
using boost::lambda;
X2 x;
transform(..., (bind(std::make_pair<X,X2>, _1, ref(x))));
```

I cant check at the moment, but if recalled correctly from memory, the above is valid.

Comment: Thanks, completly forgot about that `make_pair` is a template function.

Answer (score 3):

```
std::for_each( xs.begin(), xs.end(),
               boost::bind( &pairs_vec_t::push_back, &ps,
// you need to pass a pointer —— at least for gcc.   ^ 
                            boost::bind( &std::make_pair<X,X2>, _1, X2() ) ) );
// you need to specify which make_pair to instantiate   ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks, completly forgot about that `make_pair` is a template function.

Answer (score 0):

No Boost needed. `std::bind2nd` is being deprecated in favor of `std::bind` adopted from Boost, but for now it's the standard.

```
pairs_vec_t ps( xs.size() );
transform( xs.begin(), xs.end(), ps.begin(),
    bind2nd( ptr_fun( make_pair<X,X2> ), X2() ) );
```

If you *do* have Boost, it's more efficient to `insert` a range (of `transform_iterator`) than iterate on `push_back` or pre-size:

```
pairs_vec_t ps(
    make_transform_iterator( xs.begin(), bind2nd( ptr_fun( make_pair<X,X2> ), X2() ) ),
    make_transform_iterator( xs.end(), bind2nd( ptr_fun( make_pair<X,X2> ), X2() ) ) );
```

How's that for a one-liner?